# Properties not changing on the DOM after a GET request

Tags: polymer-1.0

I am working on a component to render user details. The details are fetched from an API request and properties are updated but these changes are not reflected on the DOM.

The company I work for is still using Polymer 1.2 and I am having difficulty finding and understanding the documentation. Do I need to make the get request from the parent component or is it possible to do this directly inside the component? There is something fundamental I am not grasping about this and wondering if someone could shed some light on it for me.

Thank you.

Snippet from the template:

```
<p>{{i18n.GLOBAL_USERNAME}} - [[username]]</p>
<p>{{i18n.GLOBAL_FIRSTNAME}} - [[firstname]]</p>
<p>{{i18n.GLOBAL_LASTNAME}} - [[lastname]]</p>
<p>{{i18n.GLOBAL_EMAIL}} - [[email]]</p>
<p>{{i18n.GLOBAL_NUMBER}} - [[number]]</p>
```

Snippet from the polymer functions:

```
Polymer({
            is: 'my-component',

            properties: {
                username: { 
                    type: String, 
                    value: "n/a",
                },
                firstname: { 
                    type: String, 
                    value: "n/a"
                },
                lastname: { 
                    type: String, 
                    value: "n/a"
                },
                email: { 
                    type: String, 
                    value: "n/a"
                },
                number: { 
                    type: String, 
                    value: "n/a"
                },
            },

            ready: function () {
                var user = app.auth.hasSession()
                if (user !== null) {
                    app.getUserInfo(user.user_id, this._getUserSuccessful, this._getUserFail);
                }
            },

            _getUserSuccessful: function (res) {
                this.username = res.user.user_id
                this.firstname = res.user.firstname
                this.lastname = res.user.lastname
                this.email = res.user.email
                this.number = res.user.phone_number
                console.log("got user details")
            },
            _getUserFail: function () {
                console.log("failed to get user details")
            },
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [Polymer setter methods](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-system#make-observable-changes) instead of plain assignment.

Here's an example:

```
_getUserSuccessful: function (res) {
  this.set('username', res.user.user_id)
  this.set('firstname', res.user.firstname)
  this.set('lastname', res.user.lastname)
  this.set('email', res.user.email)
  this.set('number', res.user.number)
  console.log("got user details")
},
```

Using setter and/or array mutator methods is required for data-bound properties otherwise Polymer can't know that something has changed in order to update the bindings.

I'd really suggest you read the whole [Data system concepts](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-system) article before moving forward with doing any kind of work with Polymer 1.x.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have tried this.set() previously as you mention but it results in an error 'Uncaught TypeError: this.set is not a function'. Based on the documentation I thought this.set() was primarily used to notify polymer of changes to subproperties so I had abandoned this approach.

Comment: You get that error because you're probably calling `_getUserSuccessful` without binding `this` properly, therefore `this` in `_getUserSuccessful` doesn't actually refer to the Polymer element in question. Add the calling code in your question as well and let me know so I can check again.

Comment: Ahh this was what I needed! Added the following line to my ready function: ```this._getUserSuccessful = this._getUserSuccessful.bind(this);``` Thank you so much.